# Is NSTextView appropriate for a chat text view?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nstextview, nswindowcontroller

I need to develop a chat window kind of view, with the following requirements:

1. Be able to display an image
2. have custom control like a progress bar
3. scrollable, and finally,
4. copy and paste

I want to know which class should I use. Can I achieved all the above using `NSTextView` or should  I go with a `NSView` and keep ScrollView inside it (drawing the text and other custom controls manually)

I appreciate your valuable comment
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just drag a nstextfield in your window in the interface builder. It will be much easier

Comment: A text field is for a single line of text, not a chat history.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, my doubt is, if i take NSTextField, it does support all the features related to text, but will i be able to show Image, Progress bar when user is sending file etc…

Comment: I think there are two options. 1: A subclass of NSTextfield 2: you put the progress bars and images on the same view as the textfield [[textfield superview] addSubview:progressBar] You can also set the size of your field. So it will look larger.